# Using prebuilt templates in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, templates

I use WordPress and either use Bones or make my own templates in the child theme of say, the Twenty Twelve theme.

How would I go about using prebuilt templates in wordpress? Such as [HTML5 templates](http://html5templates.com/).

Would it be a simple copy and paste somewhere, then adding the PHP calls in? (I'm not too familiar with PHP, just know the very basic stuff).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Foundation templates, such as Joints, which worked a treat.